# OpenSSH: allow users with writeable HOME to use public key authentication

Tags: ssh, permissions, authentication, public-key, home-directory

On a local workstation I need to have a handful of users to be able to freely write in each other $HOME.

I *KNOW* this is a security breach and, in the specific situation, I do not care at all.

I have another server (not local to LAN) used mainly as SCM repo.
The above mentioned users access server via ssh.

Unfortunately OpenSSH server does not like writable $HOMEs and I found *no* way to circumvent it (I expected to have some server-side param).

Can someone suggest a workaround?

Comment: Please, try to explain better what is the requirement here, what are you trying to do; this sounds like unneeded pain with probably a better solution.

Comment: @dawud: There are a handful of developers working on this private machine and they need to exchange files and also edit files or compile code residing under a co-worker HOME, so their HOME is 0777. I tried convincing them to use some external place, but they wouldn't listen (and I do not want to force them). In this condition they are unable to use rsa authentication to access *another* machine (target or git server).

Comment: Either they are competent enough to provide a working environment for their own use, or they have to accept the solution given by whoever manages the systems. The solution is obvious: every user has a personal account and a clone of the repository. File exchanges out of the scope of the repository can happen on an SFTP server. Problem with ssh keys has gone away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion for a workaround: Put the authorized_keys file somewhere outside of the user's home directory, using the `AuthorizedKeysFile` directive in sshd's config file.

However, I'm a bit puzzled - the `StrictModes` directive should specifically do what you want. Does this not work as documented?

> StrictModes
>
> Specifies whether sshd should check file modes and ownership of
>            the user's files and home directory before accepting login.  This
>            is normally desirable because novices sometimes accidentally
>            leave their directory or files world-writable.  The default is
>            "yes".

Comment: Current OpenSSH does exist without a StrictModes option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: groups.

Make all the users the member of the same group, and make <strike>their $HOME directories</strike> some "workspace" folder group-writable.

Due to restrictions on the permissions that SSH will allow on the $HOME directories (as mentioned in the comments below), the only way to make this work would be to create a folder they can all access elsewhere, and perhaps place a link to it in each $HOME directory. This can be done automatically using the `/etc/skel` directory.

Comment: Are You sure? Man page says max permission is 0755, with an exception (debian) if you have 0775 **and** you are the *only* use in your group.

Comment: Ah, you're correct. I'll update my answer.